How to wire outlet and recessed lights same circuit | 14-3 romex
Currently, a wall switch is controlling power to an outlet for a lamp as the room's source of light. I need to update the old, outdated outlet and wanted to take the opportunity to make some changes to how the room is lit, and the outlet powered.
Currently, 14-3 is running from the wall switch to a splice connection in a junction box, where 14-3 continues down to the outlet. The junction box was added when we had some old wiring updated.
What is the proper way to:
--power the outlet as always on so that it isn't controlled by the wall switch
--have the wall switch control 2 new recessed lights that will be put in


Is your receptacle half switched?

"/3" is not normally needed to feed the switch, so a complete description of wires in the j-box or a picture would be great.

@NoSparksPlease good question. I believe it was, though sad to say that it's been so long that the switch/outlet have been used and the outlet removed, I don't recall.

@NoSparksPlease picture updated. When the new wiring was installed, all wires were connected. I don't believe this is how it was wired previously. The updated 14-3 was left looped and taped off in the wall box where the new outlet was to go. edit: green older wire is coming from the wall switch, white new wire is going down to the oulet.

Is the box shown ahead of or after the switch?

@NoSparksPlease after the switch. edit: previously the green wire coming from the switch (now spliced in the jbox) ran straight over/down to the outlet

Two code violations exist here, 6" of free conductor is required https://up.codes/viewer/colorado/nfpa-70-2023/chapter/3/wiring-methods-and-materials#300.14 and your j-box is required to be grounded https://up.codes/viewer/colorado/nfpa-70-2023/chapter/2/wiring-and-protection#250.148_(C) .

@NoSparksPlease roger that. Will have that updated and appreciate you pointing that out.

@NoSparksPlease you're a rock star. This is what I presumed, though have little experience with 14/3 and wanted to seek advice. Thank you for your help and for pointing out those two issues as well. Consider it done. Happy Holidays!

Remove the existing 14/3 that is legally too short. Run new 14/2 to new receptacle. Connect to black/white/ground. Run new 14/2 to new lights, connect this black to red, white to white and ground to ground. Test. If receptacle stays hot you are good to go. If switch controls receptacle then swap blacks from 14/2's to opposite colors from 14/3.

Looks like there might be some slack in the 14/3 that might bring it up to code.
